# select all jobs that a user hasn't already applied for

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am wondering what would be the best way to get all jobs from a jobs table for a user that isn't referenced in the `apply_jobs` pivot table?

Comment: Please elaborate more. What is this Apply_Jobs table? What is inside Jobs table?

Comment: The apply_jobs table is a link between the users and jobs table, when a user applies for a job it adds the user_id and job_id into the table. I can get all the info but am stuck on the query structure using eloquent.                What I would like to do is select all from jobs table that the user hasn’t already applied for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job.
You select the unique job ids from apply_job table where your user did not apply. You then look for those jobs. **This is not tested.**

```
Jobs::whereIn('id', function($query)
{
  $query->select(DB::raw('distinct(job_id)'))
        ->from('apply_job')
        ->where('user_id != CURRENT_USER_ID');
})
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and effort Boris, I sorted another way to do it before if saw your post.

I went with 

> $check = ApplyJob::pluck('job_id')->all();
> $jobs = Job::whereNotIn('id', $check)->Paginate(5);